# set focus on blackberry custom button field

Tags: blackberry

i am new in blackberry,

i am using custom Image Button field, like tabs, i have 3 image buttons(like tabs) and 3 screens.All 3 screens have that 3 image buttons, if i click 2 imagebutton it navigate to next screen. It focused first image button only(first tab), but i want, it will focus at second image button, any one can help me here my code,

ImageButtonField.java

```
public class ImageButtonField  extends ButtonField {
Bitmap mNormal;
Bitmap mFocused;
Bitmap mActive;

String text;
int mWidth;
int mHeight;

public ImageButtonField(Bitmap normalImage, Bitmap focusedImage, 
    Bitmap activeImage,String text) {
    super(CONSUME_CLICK);
    this.text=text;
    mNormal = normalImage;
    mFocused = focusedImage;
    mActive = activeImage;
    mWidth = mNormal.getWidth();
    mHeight = mNormal.getHeight();
    setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
    setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);     
    setBorder(BorderFactory
                .createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(0, 0, 0, 0)));
    setBorder(VISUAL_STATE_ACTIVE, BorderFactory
            .createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(0, 0, 0, 0)));
}

protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    switch (getVisualState()) {
    case VISUAL_STATE_NORMAL:
        bitmap = mNormal;
        break;
    case VISUAL_STATE_FOCUS:
        bitmap = mFocused;
        break;
    case VISUAL_STATE_ACTIVE:
        bitmap = mActive;
        break;
    default:
        bitmap = mNormal;
    }
    graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(),
            bitmap, 0, 0);
    if(text!=null)
    {
        graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
     graphics.setFont(getFont().derive(Font.BOLD, 28));
    // graphics.
    graphics.drawText(text,50, 30);
    }


}

public int getPreferredWidth() {
    return mWidth;
}

public int getPreferredHeight() {
    return mHeight;
}

protected void layout(int width, int height) {
    setExtent(mWidth, mHeight);

}
}
```

HomeScreen.java

```
public final class HomeScreen extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener {

private Bitmap homeImageOn;
private Bitmap activateImageOn;
private Bitmap socialImageOn;
private Bitmap homeImageOff;
private Bitmap activateImageOff;
private Bitmap socialImageOff;
private Bitmap logo;
private Bitmap driveNowTextBgImage;
private Bitmap webLink1Image;
private Bitmap webLink2Image;

ImageButtonField homeBitmapImageResource;
ImageButtonField activateBitmapImageResource;
ImageButtonField socialBitmapImageResource;
ImageButtonField logoBitmapResource;
ImageButtonField driveNowBgImageButtonField;

BitmapField webLink1BitmapResorce;
BitmapField webLink2BitmapResorce;

/**
 * Creates a new HomeScreen object
 */
public HomeScreen() {
    // Set the displayed title of the screen
    HorizontalFieldManager tabHorizantalManager = new HorizontalFieldManager();
    VerticalFieldManager contentVerticalManager = new VerticalFieldManager();



    homeImageOn = Bitmap.getBitmapResource( "home-on.png");
    activateImageOff = Bitmap.getBitmapResource( "activate-off.png");
    socialImageOff = Bitmap.getBitmapResource( "social-off.png");
    homeImageOff = Bitmap.getBitmapResource( "home-off.png");
    activateImageOn = Bitmap.getBitmapResource( "activate-on.png");
    socialImageOn = Bitmap.getBitmapResource( "social-on.png");


    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("bg.png");
    getMainManager().setBackground(
            BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(bitmap));

    homeBitmapImageResource = new ImageButtonField(homeImageOff,
            homeImageOn, homeImageOff, null);
    activateBitmapImageResource = new ImageButtonField(activateImageOff,
            activateImageOn, activateImageOff, null);
    socialBitmapImageResource = new ImageButtonField(socialImageOff,
            socialImageOn, socialImageOff, null);




    tabHorizantalManager.add(homeBitmapImageResource);
    tabHorizantalManager.add(activateBitmapImageResource);
    tabHorizantalManager.add(socialBitmapImageResource);



    add(tabHorizantalManager);


    socialBitmapImageResource.setChangeListener(this);
    activateBitmapImageResource.setChangeListener(this);
    homeBitmapImageResource.setChangeListener(this);

}

public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (field.equals(homeBitmapImageResource)) {
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new HomeScreen());
    }
    if (field.equals(activateBitmapImageResource)) {

        ActivateScreen activateScreen = new ActivateScreen();
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(activateScreen);            
        System.out.println("Button pressed: ");
    }
    if (field.equals(socialBitmapImageResource)) {
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new SocialScreen());

    }
}
}
```

Comment: have you looked [at this blackberry example](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Create-tabbed-view-screens/ta-p/444969)?  I know it's using `LabelFields` and not your custom image button fields, but it might be a good place to start.  you might try replacing your `ImageButtonField` with a simpler, built-in Field (like a LabelField) and make sure you can get that working first.  Then, add in your ImageButtonField.

Comment: i got solution for above problem here my solution code, protected void onDisplay(){   
  socialImageButtonField.setFocus();
 }

Answer (score 2):

i got solution for above problem here my solution code,

```
protected void onDisplay(){
socialImageButtonField.setFocus(); 
}
```